# Can someone give me a definition of "type hinting" for Laravel 5 framework

Tags: php, laravel-5, frameworks

I've  read the Laravel documentation and it's still not clear. Since it's vague to me, whenever the term arises in relation to another concept, it's hard to grasp that new concept as well.

Comment: See here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Answer (score 30):

Type-hinting isn't exclusive to Laravel... Here is a simple explanation.

Example without type hinting:

```
function foo ($arr = array(), $str = '') {
    var_dump($arr);
    var_dump($str);
}
```

This function expects an array as the first parameter, and a string as the second. But there is nothing enforcing it. I could call `foo()` with two strings and there would be no issues.

Example with type hinting:

```
function foo (array $arr = array(), $str = '') {
    var_dump($arr);
    var_dump($str);
}
```

The only difference here is the type hint `array` before `$arr`. Now trying to call the function with two strings will return a fatal error, because the first argument must be an array.

For further explanation and to find out which type hints are supported, see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

Answer (score 27):

The Laravel service container is used to resolve all Laravel controllers. As a result, you are able to type-hint any dependencies your controller may need in its constructor. The declared dependencies will automatically be resolved and injected into the controller instance:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\UserRepository;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The user repository instance.
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  UserRepository  $users
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }
}
```

As you can see, controller will automatically create an instance of App\Repositories\UserRepository for you, and this is really handy

You can read more about these functionality [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container)

Comment: By the way, `Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher` call `resolveClassMethodDependencies()`  function from `Illuminate\Routing\RouteDependencyResolverTrait` trait to initialize all paramers you placed as function arguments in your controller

Comment: This is the actual answer!